# Node Creation in Magnolia CMS

Tags: java, content-management-system, jcr, magnolia

I'm working in a Magnolia CMS project already started. In the very beginning I read the documentation and followed the academy class they have in the web. After that I was entrusted to build a new module. The easiest way is copying an existing one. I did that but it didn't worked as expected. I modified the path but still don't work as expected. So I discovered I have to create a node which the new module has to point. I don't know how to create a `[mgnl:content]`. Does someone has experience on it and could give me a hand? Thanks on advance!

Answer (score 2):

To create a node you can just call `MgnlContext.getJCRSession("workspace name").getRootNode().addNode("path/to/my/node", "mgnl:content")` however that is **NOT** what you want to do here.

All you should need to do here is write your module descriptor right and place it in correct location in your module structure. Read more about it in [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Module+descriptor).

Another misconception in your post is to think that copying module is easiest way to make one. That's totally wrong. The best way to make a module is to use maven archetype `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/`
and again there's more explanation about it in [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Creating+a+custom+bundle).

Comment: Jan, thanks for you prompt answer, but due to my ignorance I'm flying blind. I'm trying to understand what it's done and include what I need. A module is done. It has subapp and each one has their [mgnl:content] where the path is pointing. I need to make a [mgnl:content] for the new subapp to point at. I appreciate any help. Many thanks!

Comment: sounds more like you are developing an app rather than module (the two are not the same, one module can have multiple apps). And not even full app but only subapp in existing app. To do that it should be enough to just create the node via Magnolia UI and configure all necessary properties and subnodes. Maybe you want to go through tutorial of writing complete app to get familiar with different parts of app development. You can find one such tutorial at https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/My+first+content+app

Comment: I followed the tutorial, in the part:  
Here are ways to create your own content app:
Option 1: Copy an app
Copy the configuration nodes of an existing content app into a new app. You can copy one of Magnolia's native apps such as Contacts.
Export the copied configuration nodes into XML.
Open the XML in a text editor. Search and replace the item names. For example, if your app manages apples instead of oranges, replace apple with orange.
Import the XML back to Magnolia.
Register a new workspace in the module descriptor and create a new node type. I can't register the app.

Comment: yeah that will not work unless you do also last step mentioned on the page - "Register a new workspace in the module descriptor and create a new node type."  W/o that, no node type is registered and app is not created.

Comment: maybe, just maybe, if you have groovy module installed, it would be enough for you to use script described at https://weblogs.java.net/blog/rah003/archive/2014/09/28/geeky-script-speed-your-app-development?force=261 to create the app. Or if you are using latest version of Magnolia I think script is also included directly in the samples in groovy module.

Answer (score 2):

You can create new Node type by adding following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodeTypes xmlns:mgnl="http://www.magnolia.info/jcr/mgnl">

  <nodeType name="mgnl:navitem" isMixin="false" hasOrderableChildNodes="true" primaryItemName="">
    <supertypes>
      <supertype>mgnl:content</supertype>
    </supertypes>
  </nodeType>
</nodeTypes>
```

This should go under:

`{mgnl-root}/{mgnl-module-name}/resources/mgnl-nodetypes/navitem.xml`

Answer (score 0):

That´s my definition of nodetype:

```
<nodeTypes
    xmlns:rep="internal"
    xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    xmlns:mix="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/mix/1.0"
    xmlns:mgnl="http://www.magnolia.info/jcr/mgnl"
    xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0">
  <!-- custom node types -->
  <nodeType name="mgnl:(YOUR NODETYPE´S NAME)" isMixin="false" hasOrderableChildNodes="true" primaryItemName="">
    <supertypes>
      <supertype>mgnl:content</supertype>
    </supertypes>
  </nodeType>
</nodeTypes>
```

This definition in your folder : \src\main\resources\mgnl-nodetypes